# Eloquent saveMany

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

Why can't I retrieve my associated collection after using saveMany? When I do the following below, the data saves properly but my association is empty.

```
$event = new Event();
$signup = new Signup();
$signup->name = "James";
$signup2 = new Signup();
$signup2->name = "Joe";
$signups = array($signup, $signup2);
$event->signups()->saveMany($signups);

$event->signups // empty collection
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're sure that the data is saved correctly, then I suppose you call `$event->signups` somewhere, before the `saveMany` call. That said, the collection is already fetched (it's empty) so you need to reload it `$event->load('signups')->signups; // will contain these 2 models`. Other reason would be wrong relation definition, but then the data would not be saved of course.

Comment: Thanks. I did that actually. Forgot to amend this post.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk you saved me! You should post this as answer